# Roslyn C# Get the symbol definition from another class

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the following invocation in my document:

```
var myContext = new FeatureWorkflowContext(FeatureWorkflowIds.CanvasConfig, activator);
```

Using Roslyn I have successfully found the first argument

```
FeatureWorkflowIds.CanvasConfig
```

Now I would like to get it real value defined in the FeatureWorkflowIds.cs class as

```
public static readonly string CanvasConfig = "Feature.WorkflowName.CanvasConfig";
```

My goal is to simply find the *"Feature.WorkflowName.CanvasConfig"* string.

Is there a simple way of getting this done or I have to open the FeatureWorkflowIds class and search through the Syntax tree?

Answer (score 0):

If the field were const like this:

```
public const string CanvasConfig = "Feature.WorkflowName.CanvasConfig";
```

It would be easy to use the SemanticModel and get the constant value.

However, since it is not const, merely static readonly, you indeed have no other option but to investigate the source declaration.

Comment: That is what I thought... Though was hoping that there is something simpler, like using compilation or something. Sorry, been playing with Roslyn just few days